# Using parent process and child process for calling a method using c

Tags: c, linux, ipc

Ii am developing a client server file transfer using c program to manipulate the parent/child process to trigger the method for receiving file and sending file. The execution was done on ubuntu and I get a very weird output

```
listen to port 2000
waiting for client connect
client connect from "IP address":"port number"
No such file directory
done with this client sent 0 byte in 0 send
close connection
waiting for - client connect
```

This message prints again.  The last message prints again after the client send the file.  What I notice is that my server still not close.

Here is my problem, I think it's due to the process execution in server, first I use fork to create parent process and child process, the parent process will handle the sending file from client by trigger the function and the child process will trigger other function to receive the file. I am doing it like this because I plan to implement message queue in my server side which Ii would like to request my child send it into the queue and my parent will get it from the queue.  So can I know what my problem is and can I implement the message queue in the receiving/sending method or any others place ?<

The for loop for my fork()

```
 for( ; ; ) /* run forever*/ 
           {   
            clientAddressLength = sizeof(clientAddress);    
            printf ("Waiting for a client to connect...\n\n");    /* block until some client connects */    
            if ( (fileDescriptorConnection = accept(serverSocketFileDescriptor, (struct sockaddr*) &clientAddress,&clientAddressLength)) < 0 )    
            {      
            perror("accept error");     
             break; /* exit from the for loop */   
                }        
            /* convert numeric IP to readable format for displaying */   
             inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(clientAddress.sin_addr), readableIP, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);    
             printf("Client connected from %s:%d\n",readableIP, ntohs(clientAddress.sin_port) );    
              /* fork a new child process */   
             if ( (childProcessID = fork()) == 0 ) /* fork returns 0 for child */    
             {      
             close (serverSocketFileDescriptor); /* close child's copy of serverSocketFileDescriptor */       
             /* do your work*/     
              obtainFileByName(fileDescriptorConnection, fileName);      

              printf("Closing connection\n");     
               /* done */      
                close(fileDescriptorConnection);  /* close connected socket*/     
                 exit(0); /* exit child process */    
              }   
                         else if ( (childProcessID = fork()) > 0 ) /* fork returns 0 for child */    
             {      
             close (serverSocketFileDescriptor); /* close child's copy of serverSocketFileDescriptor */       
             /* do your work*/     

              fileSent(fileDescriptorConnection, fileName);      
              printf("Closing connection\n");     
               /* done */      
                close(fileDescriptorConnection);  /* close connected socket*/     
                 exit(0); /* exit child process */    
              }   
               close(fileDescriptorConnection); /* close parent's copy of fileDescriptorConnection */      
            } /* end for */      
            close(serverSocketFileDescriptor); /* close listening socket*/ 
             return 0; 
}
```

The method program that i mention

```
void obtainFileByName(int sock, char* fileName) 
{    
     /* read name of requested file from socket */     
      if ( (bytesReceive = recv(sock,  stringReceive, receivingBuffer, 0)) < 0) 
      {    
       printf("Nothing receive");   
       return; 
      }   
       sscanf ( stringReceive, "%s\n", fileName); /* discard CR/LF */  
} 
int fileSent(int sock, char *fileName) 
{  
  if( (file = open(fileName, O_RDONLY)) < 0)  /* can't open requested file */ 
   {    
   perror(fileName);    
   if( (bytesSent = send(sock, message ,strlen(message), 0)) < 0 )  
     {     
     printf("send error");     
       return -1;    
     }  
    }  
    else /* open file successful */  
    {   
     printf("Sending file: %s\n", fileName);   
      while( (bytesRead = read(file, stringSent, receivingBuffer)) > 0 )    
      {     
       if( (bytesSent = send(sock, stringSent, bytesRead, 0))< bytesRead )     
        {        
        printf("Nothing send");        
        return -1;      
        }     
         counterForSending++;     
         fileSizeSent += bytesSent;    
      }   
       close(file);  
    } /* end else */   
    printf("Done with this client. Sent %d bytes in %d send(s)\n\n", fileSizeSent, counterForSending); 
    return counterForSending; 
} <br><br> the full program will be post if needed
```

Comment: C does not support methods. You mean functions or have the wrong language.

Comment: it's function because i am more familiar in java ,method is for java

Comment: _methods_ have different semantics (see Wikipedia for instance). Do not use these names for functions.